# ReactJS - Make my homemade slideshow responsive and image-gaps proofed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I m using a homemade SlideShowUtil to display my image [like MacDonald would do](https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/product/artisan-grilled-chicken-sandwich.html) in their "Related Products" section.

***To put some context***, I have tried to download some library like:

- react-multi-carousel
- tiny-slider
- react-customizable-carousel
- slick // jquery
- siema

But none of them work well in my application -I m using NextJS, maybe it influence the result-, I dont know why but seems theses node packages make my app just breaks. So I have my homemade util on the front currently.

So my Util works well but lack of responsiveness and adaptability, when resizing the component presentation breaks.

here the sandbox of my homemade slideshow: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-lewin-88syl

MacDonald's slide even include margin between elements, awesome management of the slide's items IMHO. Currently the slideshow become more little when user restrains the screen but two issue: 
- the management of item displaying fails, item are displayed depending of the space available on the screen. 
- item are display not entirely depending of the space available.

What should I change in my code to achieve the MacDonald result?

---

***TLDR:*** 
MacDonald's slideshow is awesome, I would reproduct their design. I have seen they manage margin between image and great responsivity. theses are the point of improvement of my own code.

How could I achieve theses results? What would you advice me? 
Here my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-lewin-88syl
Here the MacDonald slide, in "Related Products" section: https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/product/artisan-grilled-chicken-sandwich.html,

thanks for any hint.